# Command to prepend string to each line?

Tags: shell

Looking for something like this? Any ideas?

```
cmd | prepend "[ERRORS] "

[ERROR] line1 text
[ERROR] line2 text
[ERROR] line3 text
... etc
```

Comment: Is there any way to set this up for all commands in bash function/script?

Comment: What is `cmd` in this case?

Comment: Does it matter? Assume is it 'ls'

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
cmd | while read line; do echo "[ERROR] $line"; done
```

has the advantage of only using bash builtins so fewer processes will be created/destroyed so it *should* be a touch faster than awk or sed.

@tzrik points out that it might also make a nice bash function.  Defining it like:

```
function prepend() { while read line; do echo "${1}${line}"; done; }
```

would allow it to be used like:

```
cmd | prepend "[ERROR] "
```

Comment: This actually only reduces the process count by one. (But it might be faster because no regexps (`sed`) or even string splitting (`awk`) are used.)

Comment: BTW, I was curious about performance and here are results of my simple benchmark using bash, sed and awk. Pushing about 1000 lines of text (dmesg output) to FIFO file and then reading them like this: http://pastebin.ca/1606844 Looks like awk is the winner. Any ideas why?

Comment: be careful running timing tests like that - try running them in all 6 different orders and then averaging the results.  Different orders to mitigate block cache effects and average to mitigate background interruption/scheduling effects.

Comment: This question is tagged "shell", not "bash".

Comment: Easy enough to wrap it in a function as well: `function prepend() { while read line; do echo "${1}${line}"; done; }`

Comment: This works well, but it masks the exit code. Is there a way to do this while preserving the exit code?

Comment: Answering my own question: To preserve the exit code, use `set -o pipefail` in your script.

Comment: How do I add the file name to this line `cmd | while read line; do echo "[ERROR] $line"; done` so that it opens the file I want?

Comment: @Nazar `cat ./your-file | while read line; do echo "[ERROR] $line"; done`

Answer (score 80):

Try this:

```
cmd | awk '{print "[ERROR] " $0}'
```

Cheers

Comment: This has the disadvantage that "[ERROR]" cannot be a variable, because the whole expression must be in single-quotes.

Comment: `awk -vT="[ERROR] " '{ print T $0 }'` or `awk -vT="[ERROR]" '{ print T " " $0 }'`

Comment: `T="[ERROR] " awk '{ print ENVIRON["T"] $0 }'` or `T="[ERROR]" awk '{ print ENVIRON["T"] " " $0 }'`

Comment: You can just exit the scope of the quotes to dereference the variable: `cmd | awk '{print "['$V]' " $0}'` - this should be evaluated once at the start, so no performance overhead.

Comment: I prefer this solution, as the bashism eats leading spaces, for instance the output of `figlet`.

Answer (score 34):

With all due credit to @grawity, I'm submitting his comment as an answer, as it seems the best answer here to me.

```
sed 's/^/[ERROR] /' cmd
```

Comment: Why is this preferable to the bash solution?

Comment: I suppose it depends on your purpose. If your goal is to simply prepend to every line in a file, this accomplishes that goal with very few characters, using a very familiar tool. I far prefer that to a 10 line bash script. The `awk` one-liner is nice enough, but I think that more people are familiar with `sed` than `awk`. The bash script is good for what it does, but it seems that it is answering a question that was not asked.

Comment: The answer that pjz submitted is also a nice one-liner. It doesn't additional programs, processes and *may* run a little quicker.

Comment: `sed X cmd` does read `cmd` and does not execute it.  Either `cmd | sed 's/^/[ERROR] /'` or `sed 's/^/[ERROR] /' <(cmd)` or `cmd > >(sed 's/^/[ERROR] /')`.  But beware the latter.  Even that this allows you to access the return value of `cmd` the `sed` runs in background, so it is likely you see the output **after** cmd finished.  Good for logging into a file, though.  And note that `awk` probably is faster than `sed`.

Comment: **Nice.**  This command is easily aliased.  `alias lpad="sed 's/^/    /'"`.  instead of ERROR I insert 4 leading spaces.  Now, for the magic trick:  `ls | lpad | pbcopy` will prepend ls output with 4 spaces which marks it as **Markdown** for *code*, meaning that you paste the clipboard (**pbcopy** grabs it, on macs) directly into StackOverflow or any other markdown context.  Couldn't `alias` the **awk** answer (on 1st try) so this one wins.  The  **while read** solution is also alias-able, but I find this **sed** more expressive.

Answer (score 14):

I created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/hilbix/speedtests) to do some speed tests.

The result is:

- In the general case, `awk` is fastest.  `sed` is a bit slower and `perl` is not much slower than `sed`.  Apparently, all those are highly optimized languages for text processing.
- In very special situations, where forks dominate, running your script as a compiled `ksh` script (`shcomp`) can save even more processing time.  In contrast, `bash` is dead slow compared to compiled `ksh` scripts.
- Creating a statically linked binary to beat `awk` seems not be worth the effort.

In contrast `python` is dead slow, but I have not tested a compiled case, because it is usually not what you would do in such a scripting case.

Following variants are tested:

```
while read line; do echo "[TEST] $line"; done
while read -r line; do echo "[TEST] $line"; done
while read -r line; do echo "[TEST]" $line; done
while read -r line; do echo "[TEST]" "$line"; done
sed 's/^/[TEST] /'
awk '{ print "[TEST] " $0 }'
awk -vT="[TEST] " '{ print T $0 }'
awk -vT="[TEST]" '{ print T " " $0 }'
awk -vT="[TEST]" 'BEGIN { T=T " "; } { print T $0 }'
T="[TEST] " awk '{ print ENVIRON["T"] $0 }'
T="[TEST]" awk '{ print ENVIRON["T"] " " $0 }'
T="[TEST]" awk 'BEGIN { T=ENVIRON["T"] " " } { print T $0 }'
perl -ne 'print "[TEST] $_"'
```

Two binary variants of one of my tools (it is not optimzed for speed, though):

```
./unbuffered.dynamic -cp'[TEST] ' -q ''
./unbuffered.static -cp'[TEST] ' -q ''
```

Python buffered:

```
python -uSc 'import sys
for line in sys.stdin: print "[TEST]",line,'
```

And Python unbuffered:

```
python -uSc 'import sys
while 1:
 line = sys.stdin.readline()
 if not line: break
 print "[TEST]",line,'
```

Comment: `awk -v T="[TEST %Y%m%d-%H%M%S] " '{ print strftime(T) $0 }'` to output a timestamp

Answer (score 6):

```
cmd | sed 's/.*/[ERROR] &/'
```

Comment: `sed 's/^/[ERROR] /'`

Answer (score 4):

I wanted a solution that handled stdout and stderr, so I wrote `prepend.sh` and put it in my path:

```
#!/bin/bash

prepend_lines(){
  local prepended=$1
  while read line; do
    echo "$prepended" "$line"
  done
}

tag=$1

shift

"$@" > >(prepend_lines "$tag") 2> >(prepend_lines "$tag" 1>&2)
```

Now I can just run `prepend.sh "[ERROR]" cmd ...`, to prepend "[ERROR]" to the output of `cmd`, and still have stderr and stdout separate.

Comment: I tried this approach but there was something going on with those `>(` subshells that I couldn't quite resolve. It seemed as though the script was completing, and the output was arriving to the terminal *after* the prompt had returned which was a bit messy. I eventually came up with the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25948606/409638

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd | xargs -L 1 -i echo "prefix{}"
```

or even easier in case `prefix` is space-delimited from the line itself

```
cmd | xargs -L 1 echo prefix
```

This is not very efficient performance-wise, but short to write.

It works by running `echo` once per each line of input. `xargs` allows you to also process `\0`-delimited lines.

Comment: This has the benefit of working on windows natively if you have xargs in your path - like in git or mingw32.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Moreutils has the `ts` command, which can be abused to do what you need:

```
cmd | ts "[ERRORS]"
```

It's probably slower than the other solutions, but much shorter...

Answer (score 2):

A solution without sed/awk and while loops:

```
cmd | xargs -n1 printf "$prefix%s\n"
```